# What is a smooth projective model of $X$ (an affine variety)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be a hypersurface defined by the equation $F(\mathbf{x}) = 0$ where $F \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, ..., x_n]$. In a paper I am reading they say let $X^c$ be  a smooth and projective model of $X$. I was wondering what was meant by this? I would greatly appreciate any assistance on this, as I could not find the meaning by googling.. Thank you very much.

Comment: I presume they mean a smooth projective variety birationally equivalent to $X$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you. Is there an easy way to obtain such a thing in general?

Comment: One word: Hironaka.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Gracious!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Just one more question. So it doesn't matter if $F$ is not homogeneous (in the question) and even in this case such model exists? (I am just concerned about the projective part..)

Comment: @JohnnyT, you take the closure of $X$ in $\Bbb P^n$ first, call it $Y$, then you resolve the singularities of $Y$. The result is projective and smooth.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Thank you!!